# Загрузка картинок в базу

Tags: php, javascript

Есть скрипт который загружает фото на страницу, вопрос как при помощи php эти загруженные фото, отправить в базу?

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

?>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div>
<form action=""method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file-field" multiple="true" />
  <input type="submit" name="send" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="img-container">
 <ul id="img-list"></ul>
</div>
<script>
// Стандарный input для файлов
  var fileInput = $('#file-field');

  // ul-список, содержащий миниатюрки выбранных файлов
  var imgList = $('ul#img-list');

  // Контейнер, куда можно помещать файлы методом drag and drop
  var dropBox = $('#img-container');

  // Обработка события выбора файлов в стандартном поле
  fileInput.bind({
    change: function() {
      displayFiles(this.files);
    }
  });

  // Обработка событий drag and drop при перетаскивании файлов на элемент dropBox
  dropBox.bind({
    dragenter: function() {
      $(this).addClass('highlighted');
      return false;
    },
    dragover: function() {
      return false;
    },
    dragleave: function() {
      $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
      return false;
    },
    drop: function(e) {
      var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      displayFiles(dt.files);
      return false;
    }
  });

  function displayFiles(files) {
    $.each(files, function(i, file) {      
      if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
    // Отсеиваем не картинки
    return true;
      }       
      // Создаем элемент li и помещаем в него название, миниатюру и progress bar,
      // а также создаем ему свойство file, куда помещаем объект File (при загрузке понадобится)
      var li = $('<li/>').appendTo(imgList);
      $('<div/>').text(file.name).appendTo(li);
      var img = $('<img/>').appendTo(li);
      $('<div/>').addClass('progress').text('0%').appendTo(li);
      li.get(0).file = file;

      // Создаем объект FileReader и по завершении чтения файла, отображаем миниатюру и обновляем
      // инфу обо всех файлах
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) {
    return function(e) {
      aImg.attr('src', e.target.result);
      aImg.attr('width', 150);
      /* ... обновляем инфу о выбранных файлах ... */
    };
      })(img);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }

  function uploadFile(file, url) {

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function() {    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
    var progress = (e.loaded * 100) / e.total;
    /* ... обновляем инфу о процессе загрузки ... */
      }
    }, false);

    /* ... можно обрабатывать еще события load и error объекта xhr.upload ... */

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if(this.status == 200) {
      /* ... все ок! смотрим в this.responseText ... */
    } else {
      /* ... ошибка! ... */
    }
      }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", url);
    var boundary = "xxxxxxxxx";    
    // Устанавливаем заголовки
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary="+boundary);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");    
    // Формируем тело запроса
    var body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='myFile'; filename='" + file.name + "'\r\n";
    body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    body += reader.result + "\r\n";
    body += "--" + boundary + "--";

    if(xhr.sendAsBinary) {
      // только для firefox
      xhr.sendAsBinary(body);
    } else {
      // chrome (так гласит спецификация W3C)
      xhr.send(body);
    }
  };
  // Читаем файл
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
</script>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

 $query = "INSERT INTO foto (img_id)VALUES 
 ('".PATH."images/')";

mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    }

?>
```

Comment: не надо пихать картинку в базу. стандартными средствами пхп аплоадим картинку в некоторую папку сервера, а в базу пишем ид картинки и абсолютный путь к ней на сервере.

Comment: для начала мне с этим бы справится, вопрос прежний, как можно все картинки загрузить в базу, причем что бы каждая картинка была отдельной записью в базе

Comment: Если решили в базу, то сохраняйте в blob полях. Гуглиться даже видео на [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPGxWaIhLmk).

Comment: KoVadim, и как это организовать в мой скрипт? что бы оно каждую фото заносило в базу которое отображается на экране ранее загружено на страницу javascriptОМ

Comment: @deivan: лучше относительный относительно вебрута. Потом переносить можно со спокойной душой и генерировать ссылки без особых напрягов.

Comment: @Fike, согласен, лучше хранить относительные пути
@KoVadim, какой смысл хранить в BLOB ?

Comment: никакого, но если @LLIAKAJI сильно хочет... пусть сделает, намучается. Почему кто то должен переубеждать его как правильно.

Comment: уже сделал и никаких проблем в этом нет, тему можно считать официально закрытой